# my data has some null values when i am trying to read the data it says "{"Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types."}

Tags: c#, nullable

PeriodStart = Convert.ToDateTime(row["PeriodStart"]),

PeriodStart = Convert.ToDateTime?(row["PeriodStart"]),

Comment: Are the values strings or DateTime? If they're DateTime use `row["..."] as DateTime`. Otherwise you'll have to use [DataRow.IsNull](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datarow.isnull?view=net-6.0) to check whether the cell contains a DBNull value before parsing.

Comment: If they are strings in the database it is always better to use a TryParse() or a TryParseExact()  instead of a Convert() I guess you did not declare the periodStart to be nullable?  like : DateTime? PeriodStart;  Since DateTime cannot be null   in that case you should use the as DateTime ?? DateTime.MinValue  ( and remember in the rest of your code that a MinValue now means that it was null in the database.)